# The difference between these 2 strings?

Tags: python, string, printing, string-formatting

I have recently started to learn Python and I am hoping that you will be able to help me with a question that has been bothering me. I have been learning Python online with [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/). In Exercise 6, I came across a problem where I was using the `%r` string formatting operation and it was resulting in two different strings. When I printed one string, I got the string with the single quotes (`' '`). With another I was getting double quotes (`" "`).

Here is the code:

```
x = "There are %d types of people." % 10
binary = "binary"
do_not = "don't"
y = "Those who know %s and those who %s." % (binary, do_not)

print "I said: %r." % x
print "I also said: %r." % y
```

The result from the first print statement:

`I said: 'There are 10 types of people.'.`

The result from the second print statement:

`I also said: "Those who know binary and those who don't.".`

I want to know why one of the statements had a result with the single quotes (`' '`) and another with (`" "`).
]
P.S. I am using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%r` is getting the `repr` version of the string:

```
>>> x = 'here'
>>> print repr(x)
'here'
```

You see, single quotes are what are normally used.  In the case of `y`, however, you have a single quote (apostrophe) inside the string.  Well, the `repr` of an object is often defined so that evaluating it as code is equal to the original object.  If Python were to use single quotes, that would result in an error:

```
>>> x = 'those who don't'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    x = 'those who don't'
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so it uses double quotes instead.

Answer (score 1):

Notice this line -> `do_not = "don't"`. There is a single quote in this string, that means that single quote has to be escaped; otherwise where would the **interpreter** know where a string *began* and *ended*? Python knows to use `""` to represent this string literal.

If we remove the `'`, then we can expect a single quote surrounding the string:

`do_not = "dont"`

`>>> I also said: 'Those who know binary and those who dont.'.`

[Single vs. double quotes in python.](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)